# How do you get the id after saving a domain object?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.3.0

How I can get the ID of a saved object.

please give me an idea. because I am a beginner in grails

```
 def saveCandidates(){
            def candidate=new Candidates(
                    name: request.getParameter('name'),
                    email: request.getParameter('email'),
                    mobile: request.getParameter('mobile')
            )
            candidate.save()
    //how i can get of candidate
           redirect(uri: request.getHeader('referer'))
            //redirect(url: request.header('referer'))
        }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `params.email` instead of `request.getParameter('email')` - this works in all controller methods.

Comment: Thanks, for your this tips.
This tip helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you save the domain

```
def candidate = new Candidates(
                name: params.name,
                email: params.email,
                mobile: params.mobile)

candidate.save()
```

you can access the id by

```
candidate.id
```